# Не работает комментарий с уведомлением

Tags: дефект

Используется Opera 46.0.2597.57 (PGO), Windows 7 64-bit.

Обнаружил, что не могу отправить уведомление пользователю в комментарии. Я ввёл символ `@`, но список с пользователями, которым можно отправить уведомление, не выпал. Когда я вручную ввёл имя пользователя, то при отправке комментария часть его урезалась (`@Newbie`) <- эта часть должна быть перед словом "уверены".

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Вы случайно не с автором вопроса или ответа разговаривали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, с автором. А вот здесь всё сработало.

Comment: [С ним, да](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697452/qtableview-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment1033281_697452). Так что это никакой не дефект :) Так и задумано.

Answer (score 4):

Это нормальное поведение когда вы отвечаете автору вопроса или ответа, к которым еще нет никаких комментариев третьих лиц.

Поскольку в таких условиях вы все равно не можете обратиться ни к какому другому адресату, а уведомление автор обсуждаемого сообщения получит в любом случае - обращение из комментария вырезается для красоты.